# Where/How to Store 3rd Party JWT on Serverless?

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, next.js

I am working with a Nextjs app and pulling data from a 3rd Party Oauth2 API. In order to make GET requests to the API I need to ensure that I have an up to date token that is refreshed every hour. What is the correct way to store this token on the backend to prevent a token call on each GET request?